# facing gradle error while running my code?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

I am facing an error while running my code. Its showing multiple lines error which you can see in the below screenshot. Kindly help me to resolve this issue[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet? Also connect to the internet and then build.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the test folder and try to rerun the project. Hopefully, the issue will be resolved.